# What're the color values for this area on a site

Tags: colors

At the top of this site: [removed] – the slightly off-white color – how do I figure out the RGB values for that color?

Or other values that I can apply to an image in Photoshop...?

The banner that's set into that area – with the photo and my name by the photo – that's a .gif and I've got the color just slightly different – I want to make the color exactly the same, so it merges into its background…

Comment: Your color is `#F8F8F9`. But you should check the aswers for interesting software that will help you next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ColorZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/colorzilla/) is a good Firefox extension that gives you an eyedropper within the browser.

Another way would be to inspect the element using Chrome developer tools, Firebug in Firefox, etc. In Chrome you do this by right-clicking on the area and clicking Inspect Element. This will give you a view similar to this, which hopefully shows you the colour value:

[image: Inspect Element]

Comment: thanks all. i see now that f8f8f9 is the color – when i create an image in that color, it looks a shade different still – i guess maybe because of the image format or something; anyway, i realized i can just make a transparent gif to resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

The color is `#f8f8f8` which is 248, 248, 248 in RGB according to http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm.

If you want to figure out yourself you just have to inspect the source of the page.
If you're on Chrome just do a right click on the element and then select `Inspect element` from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a screenshot into Photoshop: it's #f8f8f9.

You may find it easier to use a plugin like ColorPicker if you want to do this often.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:
Make a printscreen and use Photoshop, Paint.NET or any other image editor with a color picker.
Use the color picker to select that off-white color and check the color-window for the RGB values

Answer (score 0):

You can install color picker to your browser.

1. [Firefox](http://www.colorzilla.com/)
2. [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorpicker-09/jegimleidpfmpepbfajjlielaheedkdo?hl=en)

You can take a screenshot and use image editor to check you the color value.

1. Microsoft paint

   - Pick the color in eyedroper
   - click on it, you will see the values in standart windows color picker
2. Irfan View

   - Just hover the pixel
3. GIMP

   - Use the color picker again